# android app that upload video from multiple user to one youtube channel is it possible?

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api

I want to build an app than should capture a video and upload it to MY YOUTUBE Channel.That's means all the people who will use this app they capture or choose a video and upload it to my channel.I have done all kind of work the problem is uploading it to my channel.Is there any way to do this ?? if it possible please let me know the way to do this.??

Comment: You could study the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) which allows uploading videos via an API. There's also [example code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your YouTube account into a Brand Account, and then allow people to upload to this channel by making them Owners / Managers. This is explained in more detail here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007?hl=en-GB

You can learn how to make your account a Brand Account by reviewing the Docs found here: [enter link description here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283)

Hopefully this points you in the right direction...

Comment: Thank you .. but i want to allow  thousand of people will upload their video through this app .. how will i make them owners/managers ?

Comment: @MdSadikulBari  U got any solutions?